# Valor no valido al asignarle a una propiedad, Symfony - PHP

Tags: php, symfony, postman

Trabajo en una api con `symfony` - `PHP`, en los formularios los nombres de las propiedades están escritas en `camelCase` pero el `backend` lo espera con `lower_snake_case` muestro un ejemplo:

En el formulario esta de esta manera `camelCase`

```
->add('fechaInicioAnio', DateType::class)
 ->add('fechaFinAnio', DateType::class)
```

Pero en el backend lo espera de esta manera `lower_snacke_case`

```
fecha_inicio_anio
fecha_fin_anio
```

Lo que hice es poner el nombre con la nomenclatura que me pide el `backend` ahora me sale el siguiente error:

```
"config_anio_lectivo": {
                            "children": {
                                "fecha_inicio_anio": {
                                    "errors": [
                                        "Este valor no es válido."
                                    ],
```

Me dice que el valor no es valido, el valor que le asigno es el siguiente:

```
-message: "Este valor no es válido."
  -messageTemplate: "This value is not valid."
  -parameters: [▶]
  -plural: null
  -root: Symfony\Component\Form\Form {#1846 ▶}
  -propertyPath: "children[config_anio_lectivo].children[fecha_inicio_anio]"
  -invalidValue: "2017-04-24"
  -constraint:
```

Acá muestro el valor `"2017-04-24"`, no se a que se debe el error, que estoy haciendo mal?, como lo puedo corregir?

Probé haciendo lo siguiente:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    //$transformer=new DataToConfigDataTransformer(ConfiguracionQuimestres::class); ConfiguracionQuimestre
    $transformerq=new DataToConfigDataTransformer(ConfiguracionQuimestre::class);
    $builder
        ->add('fecha_inicio_anio', DateType::class, array(
            'format' => 'y-M-d'
        ))
        ->add('fecha_fin_anio', DateType::class)
        ->add('quimestre1',  ConfiguracionQuimestreType::class)
        ->add('quimestre2',  ConfiguracionQuimestreType::class)
         ConfiguracionQuimestresType::class)
    ;
   
    $builder->get('quimestre1')->addModelTransformer($transformerq);
    $builder->get('quimestre2')->addModelTransformer($transformerq);
}
```

Me sigue dando el mismo error. "Este valor no es valido".

Comment: que formato de fecha maneja el backend tienes algun ejemplo de una fecha que se haya validado???

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez es parte del JSON que estabamos viendo, todo eso se guarda en un campo de tipo longtext(65535)

Comment: esa no es la respuesta a la pregunta que te hice; no me importa de donde viene el dato; la pregunta es saber cual formato de fecha es correcto enviar a los menjor tu estas enviando una fecha incompatible ...

Comment: y-M-d no es lo mismo que 2017-04-24 creo que es 2017-april-24 creo que por hay va el asuntro o me equivoco...

Comment: Es que el JSON que cogí de la tabla esta en ese formato, por que a alguien le estaba funcionando antes que llegara, entonces he cogido uno que ya estaba y lo quiero persistir en nuevo registro.